# Finding weighted average

Tags: performance, math, weighted-average

I am trying to figure out what my overall average speed is while on a bike.

I have miles traveled in column 1 and then avg speed in miles per hour in column 2.

The problem is that I have different distances associated with the differing speeds, so I cant juts average my all of the speeds to get an accurate average.

How do I find the overall average speed, weighted, so that I have the actual avg speed?

Distance
9.82,
8.69,
8.43,
9.07,
8.16,
12.41,
7.22,
3.13,
10.28,
9.79,
10.44,

Avg Speed
18.4,
12.8,
16.7,
18.1,
16.2,
19,
13.5,
16,
10.9,
16.8,
15.6,

Comment: Pleas show the code that you've already tried and a [mre]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Very strong emphasis on **weigh by time, not by distance**. But the simplest way is to use the formula `avg_speed = total_distance / total_time`, as indicated in MBo's answer.

Comment: Related puzzle: "I want to run 20km in 2h; so, I want my average speed to be 10km/h. If I run the first half at 5km/h, what speed should I have on the second half to meet my objective?"

Answer (score 1):

How overall average speed should be calculated? As

```
Vavg_total = Distance_total / Time_total
```

We can find total distance as sum of stage sizes, and time as sum of stage times

```
Distance_total = Sum(Distance[i]) 
Time_total = Sum(Distance[i] / AvgSpeed[i])
```